# When I click 'Generate Data Layers' the pants are jumping off the body

Tags: modifiers

I try to dress the character with pants,
but when I click Generate Data Layers and Apply, the pants are jumping off the body

[image: BEFORE]

[image: After]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see if you switch your armature to its default pose, your pants are not aligned with it:

[image]

You need to correct that in *Edit* mode:

[image]

At last, in your *Data Transfer* modifier, choose *Body_Mesh.001*, not *Body_Mesh*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i will try